# Is the Android screen lock good enough to prevent access to an Android 8 device?

Tags: android, mobile

I have Android 8 mobile phone and I need to give it for mobile repair center for battery replacement. There is chip car, but there are lot of data in my phone.

What I want to know is it enough having Android Lock Screen? Can repairmen access my data?

Comment: As you are concerned about data stored in your phone, do not try factory reset. Do you have ADB, the USB port debugging turned on?

Comment: In case you have android root access or ADB access to your phone, then go to in data/system and delete locksettings .key file(s) then the password won't be needed.

Comment: How are they supposed to fix the problems without accessing the phone?

Comment: Is /data encryption enabled?

Comment: @multithr3at3d How can I enable it?

Comment: @EsaJokinen It is just battery replacement.

Comment: That should have been on the question, as it's a whole different thing. I did the edit for you.

Comment: What type of mobile phone you got and what's the vendor? It depends on that information and the android version if it's encrypted by default.

Comment: @CDRohling It is Huwaei Mate 10 Lite

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your given information it's kinda hard to answer your question. Since Android 7 [File-based Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption) have been supported. It depends on the vendor of the phone if this is activated by default. I googled a bit about your phone (Huawei Mate 10 Lite) and haven't found official information about that. On [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Huawei/comments/859443/encryption_on_mate_10/) are some questions which state that this phone needs to use this type of encryption. So if I'm refering to this and the fact that you set a secure password on your phone it is safe to hand the phone over to a repairman.

But note:
If you hand it over, take care that you cannot see traces of your finger on the damaged display. If you see 4 touches at the position of the pinpad it won't be hard to guess your password. So clean the phone before you give it to them.